# How to add the temp directory in Win 7 as a Python variable

Tags: python, string, percentage, tempdir

The temp directory in win 7 is `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp` and I'd like to add it to a python script as a variable to be used to create a text file there.

However, because of the `%` at the beginning, it makes python unable to identify it. I tried to add double `%%`, but that didn't work as well.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module instead:

```
import tempfile
my_temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
```

This is the platform-independent way to have a temporary file.

Comment: The problem with tempfile module is that the file gets deleted once closed  `fp.close()`

Comment: You can make it like `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)`